Read time out with BigQuery dry run uaing client library in Java
I am preparing a query in the code dynamically. This is a Google big query compatible query. The query has no errors and the gbq console shows no error and shows the estimated processing data size in around 2 mins. But the same query when trying to validate through bigquery library in java i am getting tine out error.
I tried setting the TotalTimeout and MaxRpcTimeout to 10 mins using bigquery options builder, still i get timeput error. I am using thunder client vs code extension for api call. This is similar to postman. I checkedd if there is timeout on the thunder client side. its already set to 0 which means no timeout as per documentation. Even with postman it times out, so looks like some issue with gbq client library.
i tried setting job timeout (8mins) in QueryJobConfiguration obj, still i am getting read timeout.
I tried setting the timeout at tomcat side, still same read timeout error.
Can anyone please help on this issue.

You are configuring query parameters, but describing timeouts received on API calls. Sounds like you're mixing up issues waiting for responses from your web application with issues from your query execution.

Issue was solved by setting read timeout on HttpTransportOptions from gbq library.
